# Invalid OpenID response: HTTP 599: SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK.

Tags: python, ssl, oauth, tornado, google-openid

I'm trying to run `authdemo.py` (`demos/auth/` folder) from Tornado 2 http://www.tornadoweb.org/ package to try out authentication mix-ins.

However I get the following error:

```
[I 110728 15:24:57 web:1235] 302 GET / (127.0.0.1) 1.00ms
[I 110728 15:24:57 web:1235] 302 GET /auth/login?next=%2F (127.0.0.1) 0.00ms
[I 110728 15:25:00 httpclient:628] POST https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud
[W 110728 15:25:01 auth:151] Invalid OpenID response: HTTP 599: SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
    error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
[W 110728 15:25:01 web:892] 500 GET /auth/login?next=......
```

I am no SSL expert so this stuff is completely cryptic to me.

Any ideas how I should start debugging this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely a certificate bundle problem. It looks like a curl error, which is weird, as curl is no longer the default HTTPClient. Are you on Python 2.5, perhaps? Try updating pycurl and libcurl, or try Python 2.6.

Comment: You were absolutely right. The error really was from curl, which shouldn't be default client in Tornado 2.0 anymore. The cause was actually very stupid: I still had old Tornado 1.0 in my site-packages -> caused the client to use CURL. I removed old tornado from Python packages and it works just fine now as CURL is no longer default in Tornado 2.

Thanks for helping me to solve this problem!